# Multiple like on same field

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

is it possible to do something like the following in MySQL:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE '%A%' AND value LIKE '%B%'`

I am trying to catch entries where "value" would be "AxBx".

Thank you for some advice!

Comment: I can't help but feel that it would take less time to actually test it out than to write a question to ask others to test it out...

Comment: I never asked you to test anything, merely if it was possible as I am getting the same error over and over again.

Comment: What error do you get? You didn't mention anything about error in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several wildcards `%` in the same `LIKE`. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE 'A%B%'
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `I am trying to catch entries where "value" would be "AxBx".` Here baik states that he wishes to find Ax Bx

Comment: This worked out good, thanks. However, I had to add `... OR value LIKE 'B%A%'` to adjust for both cases, where A comes first and A comes last.